# How do you use malloc of struct inside a function?

Tags: c

In a this code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct test
{
  int i;
  double data;
} test;

void add(ar) struct test *ar;
{
  int num = 10;
  // *ar = malloc(num * sizeof(struct test)); // Adding this
  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    ar[i].i = i;
    ar[i].data = i * i;
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  test ar[10]; // Removing this
  add(&ar);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    printf("%d %f\n", ar[i].i, ar[i].data);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

How do we define the `struct` in `main` but allocate the memory in the `function`?

I want to set the number (`num`) inside the function `add`, as it is not yet known in `main`.

Comment: if you already pass an array of structs what do you want to `malloc()` in `add()`?. And please don'r use antique K&R decarations but `void add( struct test *ar )` so your compiler can check the parameters

Comment: BTW: `void` didn't even exist in K&R times ... [and the real answer: use the return value to return things to the caller]

Comment: typedef'd struct test is defined in the file; a variable `ar` of type `struct test[]` is declared in main. but allocate which struct? everything is called `test` and `ar`, it's not easy guessing what you're thinking of here in the `//MY QUESTION` comment

Comment: @Shark I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt I don't want to pass the array of the struct, but the pointer. I want to create the array inside the function.

Comment: Who uses K&R syntax since 1989?

Comment: In your code the struct is _defined_ globally not in `main()`.  You _instantiate_ an array of structs in `main()`.  Slightly pedantic, but the answer to the question would be different if you really did intend to _define_ the struct in `main()`.

Comment: SO is not a replacement for a good book.  I might suggest: https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two values you have to pass back from `add()` to `main()`, `num` and the `malloc()`ed array itself. As you can return only one value, there are two positilities:

a) return num and have a `test **` parameter to pass back the array

```
int add( struct test **ar )
{
   int num = 10;

   *ar = malloc( num * sizeof **ar );
   // initialize everything, you have to replace ar[i] by (*ar)[i]
   return num;
}
```

call it

```
struct test *ar;
int num = add( &ar );
```

b) return the array and have a `int *` parameter to pass back num

```
struct test *add( int *num )
{
   *num = 10;
   
   struct test *ar = malloc( *num * sizeof *ar );
   // initialize everything as you do now
   return ar;
}
```

call it

```
 int num;
 struct test *ar = add( &num );
```

As @Bodo mentioned, either way, you have to call `free( ar );` in `main()` when you don't need `ar` anymore. You could call it directly or think about having a cleanup function like `free_test( struct test *ar, int num );` that does the job. Such a function is especially useful if you have more `malloc()`s to allocate memory for the single struct elements (eg. if they contained `char *` elements to store strings).

Comment: A third possibility is `int add(struct test **ar, int *num)` which returns an error status.

Comment: I suggest to add a note that `main` should call `free(ar)` either directly or via an additional cleanup function.

Comment: @bodo yeah, woth adding that. Thanks

Comment: @Ruks and the funniest things happen when you call that function twice

Answer (score 1):

- use the argument(s) to pass argument(s)
- use the return value to return stuff to the caller

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test
{
  int i;
  double data;
} ;

struct test *test_create(unsigned ntest)
{
  struct test *pp;
  unsigned idx;

  pp = malloc(sizeof *pp * ntest);
  for (idx = 0; idx < ntest; idx++)
  {
    pp[idx].i = idx;
    pp[idx].data = idx * idx;
  }

return pp;
}

int main(void)
{
  struct test *ptr;
  ptr = test_create(10);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    printf("%d %f\n", ptr[i].i, ptr[i].data);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

Update: if you want to return more than a single item, you could put the items together in a struct:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct dope {
        unsigned size;
        struct {
                int i;
                double data;
                } *array;
        } ;

struct dope *dope_create(void)
{
  struct dope *pp;
  unsigned omg =10;

  pp = malloc(sizeof *pp );
  pp->array = malloc(sizeof *pp->array * omg);
  pp->size = omg;

  for (omg = 0; omg < pp->size; omg++)
  {
    pp->array[omg].i = omg;
    pp->array[omg].data = omg * omg;
  }

return pp;
}

int main(void)
{
  struct dope *ptr;
  ptr = dope_create();

  for (int iii = 0; iii < ptr->size; iii++)
  {
    printf("%d %f\n", ptr->array[iii].i, ptr->array[iii].data);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question contains the requirement "*I want to set the number (`num`) inside the function add, as it is not yet known in main.*", so you have to return both the pointer and the number of elements. If you don't want to use arguments to return values you might have to return a structure.

Comment: BTW: that requirement was added later to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have already good answers as alternatives. Anyway I will show you code for  **2 common ways** of writing this.

As I see in your code, the *factory function* will determine the actual number of structs `test` to allocate. I will in the example:

- generate a random number of structs, using `rand()` since it makes no difference here
- fill them in like (1,1.01), (2,2.02) ... just to have a known value for testing
- show the structs' contents on screen
- free() them at exit
- assume that can also be 0 structures created

#### 1: use a NULL-terminated sequence of pointers

As it is used with success in all C strings :) we can use it here. As in strings (C strings), you need to search for the terminator in order to get the array size (Of course you can set the first pointer apart for the size, *Pascal-like*). It can or can not be of importance to know before-hand the # of structs.

```
Test**      add_vector()
{
    // returns a null terminated array of pointers
    // to 'Test', pointing to actual instances of
    // 'Test', allocated and numbered with 'i' starting
    //  at 1 and 'data' starting at 1.01
    int num = rand() % 10;  // 0 to 9 Test
    fprintf(stderr,
        "add_vector(): creating %d structs\n", num);
    // at least one pointer, the terminating one
    Test** ar = (Test**)malloc((1 + num) * sizeof(Test*));
    int    ix = 0;
    for (ix = 0; ix < num; ix += 1)
    {
        ar[ix] = (Test*)malloc(sizeof(Test));
        // sets up ar[i] to a known value
        ar[ix]->i    = 1 + ix;
        ar[ix]->data = 1 + ix + (1 + ix) / 100.;
    };              // for()
    ar[ix] = NULL;  // the terminator one, as in strings
    return ar;
}
```

To use it you just call

```
    Test** vector = add_vector();
```

as you see in the example below. A single pointer is returned. No need for arguments. If the number of structs is zero a single pointer is returned, like it would be with an empty string.

The # of structs is defined inside the function, and all structs instances are allocated and numbered before returning to caller.

#### 2: return a pointer to a struct

```
typedef struct
{
    int    i;
    double data;

}   Test;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    Test*    test;

} V_Test;

V_Test*     add_struct();
```

The allocation function returns a pointer to a `V_Test` struct, that contains an array of `Test` strucs and a `size` elements, an in `main()` for every C program

```
    int main(in argc, char** argv)
```

Here is the code:

```
V_Test*     add_struct()
{
    // returns a vector of structs inside V_Test,
    // with known 'size', like in main( int,char**) 
    // The structs are initialized with 'i' starting
    //  at 1 and 'data' starting at 1.01
    unsigned num = rand() % 10;  // 0 to 9 Test
    fprintf(stderr, "add_struct(): creating %d structs\n", num);
    V_Test* v  = (V_Test*) malloc(sizeof(V_Test));
    v->size   = num;
    if (num == 0)
    {
        v->test = NULL;
        return v;
    };
    v->test  = (Test*)malloc(num * sizeof(Test));
    for (unsigned ix = 0; ix < num; ix += 1)
    {
        v->test[ix].i = 1 + ix;
        v->test[ix].data = 1 + ix + (1 + ix) / 100.;
    };              // for()
    return v;
}
```

To used it you just call

```
    V_Test* vector = add_struct();
```

And here also there are no arguments. A new `V_Test` is allocated and returned.

Also here the # of structs is defined inside the function, and all structs instances are allocated and numbered before returning to caller.

In the code you will see a way of use both functions, create the structs, fill them in, display the contents and release the allocated memory.

#### Example output

```
add_vector(): creating 9 structs
#  1: [1, 1.01]
#  2: [2, 2.02]
#  3: [3, 3.03]
#  4: [4, 4.04]
#  5: [5, 5.05]
#  6: [6, 6.06]
#  7: [7, 7.07]
#  8: [8, 8.08]
#  9: [9, 9.09]
9 records were created
9 records were free()'d
add_struct(): creating 4 structs
#  1: [1, 1.01]
#  2: [2, 2.02]
#  3: [3, 3.03]
#  4: [4, 4.04]
4 records were created
4 records were free()'d
```

#### C Code

I compiled just once under MSVC.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int    i;
    double data;

}   Test;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned size;
    Test*    test;

} V_Test;

V_Test*     add_struct();      
Test**      add_vector();

void as_vector_of_pointers();
void as_struct_of_struct();

int main(void)
{
    srand(210728);
    as_vector_of_pointers();
    as_struct_of_struct();
    return 0;
}


Test**      add_vector()
{
    // returns a null terminated array of pointers
    // to test
    int num = rand() % 10;  // 0 to 9 Test
    fprintf(stderr,
        "add_vector(): creating %d structs\n", num);
    // at least one pointer, the terminating one
    Test** ar = (Test**)malloc((1 + num) * sizeof(Test*));
    int    ix = 0;
    for (ix = 0; ix < num; ix += 1)
    {
        ar[ix] = (Test*)malloc(sizeof(Test));
        // sets up ar[i] to a known value
        ar[ix]->i    = 1 + ix;
        ar[ix]->data = 1 + ix + (1 + ix) / 100.;
    };              // for()
    ar[ix] = NULL;  // the terminator one, as in strings
    return ar;
}


V_Test*     add_struct()
{
    // returns a vector of structs inside V_Test,
    // with known 'size', like in 
    // main( int,char**) 
    unsigned num = rand() % 10;  // 0 to 9 Test
    fprintf(stderr, "add_struct(): creating %d structs\n", num);
    V_Test* v  = (V_Test*) malloc(sizeof(V_Test));
    v->size   = num;
    if (num == 0)
    {
        v->test = NULL;
        return v;
    };
    v->test  = (Test*)malloc(num * sizeof(Test));
    for (unsigned ix = 0; ix < num; ix += 1)
    {
        v->test[ix].i = 1 + ix;
        v->test[ix].data = 1 + ix + (1 + ix) / 100.;
    };              // for()
    return v;
}


void as_struct_of_struct()
{
    V_Test* vector = add_struct();
    if (vector->size == 0)
    {
        printf("No records were created!\n");
        free(vector);
        return;
    }
    for ( unsigned count = 0; count < vector->size; count+=1)
    {
        printf("#%3d: [%d, %.2f]\n",
            1 + count,
            vector->test[count].i,
            vector->test[count].data
        );
    };  // for()
    printf("%d records were created\n", vector->size);

    // to free() vector:
    free(vector->test);
    printf("%d records were free()'d\n", vector->size);
    free(vector);
    return;
};


void as_vector_of_pointers()
{
    Test** vector = add_vector();
    // now test the vector to count the number of
    // records generated in the funcion
    if (vector[0] == NULL)
    {
        printf("No records were created!\n");
        free(vector);
        return;
    }
    unsigned count = 0;
    while (vector[count] != NULL)
    {
        printf("#%3d: [%d, %.2f]\n", 1 + count, (vector[count])->i,
               (vector[count])->data);
        count += 1;
    };
    printf("%d records were created\n", count);

    // to free() vector, same way:
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < count; i += 1) free(vector[i]);
    free(vector);
    printf("%d records were free()'d\n", count);
    return;
}
```

> *SO* vigilants: I always cast `malloc()` pointers, as I reminder to
> myself and others reading the code. No implicit conversions. No need to pointing that.